# 2-dimension array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Ok i'm really confused with arrays and pointers here.

I'm trying to move a simple block of code to C, but unfortunately I'm failing misserably..

```
char tictactoe[3][6];

tictactoe[0]="-|-|-";
tictactoe[1]="-|-|-";
tictactoe[2]="-|-|-";
```

I get this compiler error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[6]' from type 'char *'
```

Could someone assist me with the correct syntax here please?

Comment: Do you want use 2D array or pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL-TR?

The short answer to your problem is this, either use:

```
char tictactoe[3][6] = {"-|-|-","-|-|-","-|-|-"};
```

Or use this, to assign on-the-fly

```
#include <string.h>

void t_t_toe( void )
{
    int i;
    char tictactoe[3][6];
    for (i=0;i<3;++i) strncpy(tictactoe[i], "-|-|-", 6);
    tictactoe[1][0] = '+';//works fine now
}
```

Here's why and when to use what:

You're confused with the subtle, yet fundamental, distinction between arrays and char pointers. It's quite easy, really, but it's a common pitfall:

```
char *string = "foobar";
char string2[] = "foobar";
```

Now, both of these statements *seem* to do the same thing, but where the first declares a pointer to a char/chars, the latter declares *an array of chars*. What's the difference? simple:

```
char *string = "foobar";
```

creates a constant array of chars, and stores that in a section of read-only stack memory. The location where *"foobar"* resides in memory (the memory address) is then assigned to `*string`.
That means that

```
printf("%c", string[1]);
```

Will indeed print out *o*, but

```
string[1] = 'Q';
```

will fail, as it attempts to reassign a value in *read-only* memory. No can do.
As opposed to the second example, where you will create the same constant char array, but it's *copied* to the array in read-write stack memory. They will behave in exactly the same way, right up to the point where you'll attempt to change the strings. as I explained, using a pointer to a constant string won't work, but because the second example *copies* the string:

```
string2[1] = 'Q';
```

will work perfectly.

Now, your case: depending on your needs, this will work just fine:

```
char *ticktacktoe[3] = {"-|-|-","-|-|-","-|-|-"};
```

This initializes an array of 3 char pointers, and assigns them the addresses of the 3 char constants *"-|-|-"*. The array will look like:

```
{ 0xabc123f4, 0xabc123f8, 0xabc123fb} //or something similar
```

What you won't be able to do, however is *reassign* the strings in the array, so you effectively declare a `const char *ticktacktoe[3]`.
If you want to be able to change the values of the strings writing:

```
char ticktacktoe[3][10] = {"tick", "tack", "toe"};
```

works just fine... to assign strings to a 2D array, it's probably best to use `strncpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

void t_t_toe( void )
{
    int i;
    char tictactoe[3][6];
    for (i=0;i<3;++i) strncpy(tictactoe[i], "-|-|-", 6);
    tictactoe[1][0] = '+';//works fine now
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thorough explanation! I want to be able to change the values later on, so this cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

```
    {//by array
        char tictactoe[3][6] ={
            "-|-|-",
            "-|-|-",
            "-|-|-"
        };
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", tictactoe[0], tictactoe[1], tictactoe[2]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    {//by pointer (in C99)
        char *tictactoe[3];
        tictactoe[0] = (char[]){ "-|-|-" };
        tictactoe[1] = (char[]){ "-|-|-" };
        tictactoe[2] = (char[]){ "-|-|-" };
        tictactoe[0][0]='X';//rewritable
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", tictactoe[0], tictactoe[1], tictactoe[2]);
    }
```

Comment: The `(char[])` cast is something I'd consider misleading. The assignments still assign addresses to read-only strings, so `ticktacktoe[0][1] = '+';` will result in a compiler error, still. The two approaches aren't compatible

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You're misunderstanding. Please use the C99 compiler. It can rewrite this.

Comment: True, didn't test with the `{ "str"}`, instead used `"str"`, which results in an invalid cast error (obviously)... however, returning this from a function (`char **test_func( void )`) does result in an error (returning address of local variable), no big deal, but still

Comment: :-) I've often said it: I'm a prime candidate for the _pedantic_ badge, if ever they introduce it on SO...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char tictactoe[3][6] = {"-|-|-","-|-|-","-|-|-"};
```

Answer (score 0):

`tictactoe[0],
tictactoe[1],
tictactoe[2]` all are of type `char[6]` and decays to the pointer to first element of their corresponding rows. You can't assign string to it. If you wanna use pointers then declare an array of pointers

```
char *tictactoe[3];
```

then assign the string as

```
tictactoe[0]="-|-|-";
tictactoe[1]="-|-|-";
tictactoe[2]="-|-|-";
```

Comment: Didn't DV, but perhaps somebody felt as though your answer didn't clear things up. Your snippet is valid code, but perhaps not answering the question? (I just answered you _why the DV?_ question because I, too, hate it when people -1 without explaining)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem; You explained well the issue in your answer. I saw. But I think my answer clears up the thing in short (I did some edit now) and now I am thinking that no issue with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following form:

```
char tic[3][6]={{'-','|','-','|','-'},{'-','|','-','|','-'},{'-','|','-','|','-'}};
```

First of all you are trying to to use CHAR type so assigning in the above form will make the correct sense.

What i think if you want to assign in **tictactoe[0]="-|-|-";** form it treats it as **pointer of CHAR**.

If you want to use same form you can make use of pointer.

Comment: `char[10] = {'f','o','o'};` != `char[10] = "foo";`, you forgot the `\0` char at the end of your strings... Should be `char[10] = {'f','o','o', '\0'};`

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
char tictactoe[3][6] = {"-|-|-", "-|-|-", "-|-|-"};
```

Answer (score -1):

1) zero terminated strings are zero terminated. You have 6 characters + terminator = you need 7 characters per row.

2) you cannot assign string literal to an array. you have to use strcpy.

Comment: point 2 is wrong `char foo[3][10] = {"bar", "zar", "car"};` compiles just fine using gcc, point 1 is not an issue because _"-|-|-"_ has only 5 chars, an array of 6 is big enough

Comment: you were right with the 5 characters. However, it is something different ti initialize an array with a constant and with assignment of literal to array. This is not the same...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"assignment of literal to array"_, but if you look at my answer, I think it fair to say I'm well aware of the differences between `char *foo = "constant";` and `char foo[10] = "bar";`, the latter being the same thing as `char foo = {'b','a','r','\0'};`, assigning a constant to an array is impossible, but a literal can be used to initialize the array